# Can I access in ActiveX project functions from another ATL simple object in the same project?

Tags: c++, com, activex

I have an ActiveX control project (.ocx) which contains one main control class and several other ATL simple objects. The main control class exposes many functions; it would be practical if I could use some of these functions in the other ATL objects. Is this possible? Do I have to instantiate my ActiveX control within one of its exported ATL objects (and how?), or is there another way?

Comment: Use `CoCreateInstance()` like you would to create any COM object.

Comment: I think you should consider reactoring your functionality. if your .ocx exposes functionality worth using by another component (or anything that would not normally host an .ocx), it's most likely exposed in the wrong place. Try separating that functionality into its own component (or perhaps as part of one of the existing components). If the functionality does not make sense to an external client outside of the context of the OCX, then maybe move the functionality to regular C++ classes available internally to all the COM objects, and make the OCX simply forward the calls to this C++ class.

Answer (score 1):

Although you did not mention it in your question I am assuming you do not currently have access to the interface/coclass decalration of the object you want to create.

If the control you want to use has an application ID associated with it you can use the [`#import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) directive to pull in the interface and type definitions directly into your C++ source file. For example if the application ID is "Library.MainObject" you could do something like below

```
#import "progid:Library.MainObject"
```

This will access the objects type library directly. If it doesn't have an application ID associated with it there are a few extra steps that you may have to take. One way to acquire the type library is to use the OLE Object Viewer utility that ships with Visual Studio. Once you find it in the Object Viewer you can save the type library as a file. If you can't find it in the Object Viewer you can try opening the OCX module directly and if it contains a type library you can export it to a file. Once you have the type library you can use `#import` to pull in the declarations.

```
#import "typelibraryname.tlb"
```

Once you have access to the declarations you can call `CoCreateInstance` just like you would for any other COM object. You can use __uuidof(typename) to get the GUID of an interface or co-class.